# Align a multiple select form-control with a normal select

Tags: bootstrap-4

[image: Multiple Select]

How can I align the above drop-downs (Server and Service(s)) within the bootstrap framework? I have tried adding my own custom css to the page but it doesn't make any difference. I also tried inline css like style="vertical-align".

Here's the code

```
                 <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col form-inline">
                        <label for="server" class="col-sm-2">Server</label>
                        <select th:field="*{subscriberSubscription.serverId}" id="server"
                                class="form-control col-sm-3">
                            <option value="">Select Server</option>
                            <option
                                    th:each="server : ${servers}"
                                    th:value="${server.id}"
                                    th:text="${server.ipAddress} + ' ' + ${#strings.defaultString(server.name,'')}"
                                    th:title="${#strings.defaultString(server.operatingSystemInfo,'')}+'&#10;'+
                                    ${#strings.defaultString(server.processorInfo,'')}
                                    +'&#10;'+${#strings.defaultString(server.RAMInfo,'')}">
                            </option>
                        </select>
                        <label for="service" class="col-sm-2">Service(s)</label>
                        <select th:field="*{subscriberSubscription.serviceIds}" id="service"
                                class="form-control col-sm-3" multiple>
                            <option
                                    th:each="service : ${services}"
                                    th:value="${service.id}"
                                    th:text="${service.displayName == null} ? ${service.name} :
                                     ${service.displayName}">
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by align? is it you want to start both from the same top margin/padding?

Comment: @Deepak Yes, I want the top to be aligned.

Comment: are u using bootstrap?

Comment: @Deepak Yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
     <label for="server" class="col">Server</label>
  <select th:field="*{subscriberSubscription.serverId}" id="server"
   class="form-control">
   <option value="">Select Server</option>
   <option
    th:each="server : ${servers}"
    th:value="${server.id}"
    th:text="${server.ipAddress} + ' ' + ${#strings.defaultString(server.name,'')}"
    th:title="${#strings.defaultString(server.operatingSystemInfo,'')}+'&#10;'+
    ${#strings.defaultString(server.processorInfo,'')}
    +'&#10;'+${#strings.defaultString(server.RAMInfo,'')}">
   </option>
  </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label for="service" class="col">Service(s)</label>
  <select th:field="*{subscriberSubscription.serviceIds}" id="service"
   class="form-control col" multiple>
   <option
    th:each="service : ${services}"
    th:value="${service.id}"
    th:text="${service.displayName == null} ? ${service.name} :
     ${service.displayName}">
   </option>
  </select>
    </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using row and col in Bootstrap will solve your problem of alignment, maybe this is what you looking for, let me know if it works for you

Comment: The drop-downs aligned with your change but the labels go on top of them. I opted to add the elements into a table instead of using bootstrap classes and that helped. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: using table will make your page less or no responsive